# git alias ssh-add .gitconfig

Tags: git, ssh, alias

In `.gitconfig` I created an alias of this type:

```
[alias]
    something = "!eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_acub && git config --global user.email <email> && git config --global user.name <user.name>"
```

At this point, running `git something` displays the information correctly, but it does not work as I expected.

If I type a line in the console:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_acub && git config --global user.email <email> && git config --global user.name <user.name>
```

then everything works well.

What is wrong in the alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler example than `ssh-agent -s`:

```
$ sh -c 'FOO=bar; echo FOO is now $FOO'
FOO is now bar
$ echo FOO is now $FOO
FOO is now
```

Why didn't this work?  Why is my login shell's `FOO` variable not set, when I set some other shell instance's `FOO` variable?

Well, I hope the answer is obvious: *my* shell does not have `FOO` set.  I set some *other* shell's `FOO` variable.  I told that *other* shell to print it, and it was set.  Then that *other* shell finished—exited—and gave control back to my login shell, and when I told my login shell to print my login shell's `FOO`, it was not set.

What `ssh-agent -s` does is *print out* some set of assignments.  Let's try that:

```
$ sh -c 'echo FOO=bar'
FOO=bar
$ echo FOO is now $FOO
FOO is now
```

This did not work either, of course, because I simply *printed some instructions*.  No one followed those instructions.

So let's try one more thing:

```
$ eval `sh -c 'echo FOO=bar'`
$ echo FOO is now $FOO
FOO is now bar
```

This time, I:

- had another command print some instructions
- told *my* shell to *follow* those instructions
- and then had my shell print out my shell's setting for `$FOO`

and since the instructions I had my shell follow *changed* something *in* my shell, *now* my shell's FOO is set.

The design for `ssh-agent` is the same: it does some work, then—in various modes including with `-s`—*prints out instructions* for some shell to follow.  You need the `eval` to make that shell follow those instructions.

That's all good and does just what you want as long as the shell that's following these instructions is *your* shell.  But when you make a Git alias, Git itself runs a *new, different* shell.  That shell follows the instructions, and when it is done, your shell is unaffected.

What this means is that you cannot do what you want with a Git alias.  You must use an alias or function that will affect *your* shell, not one that will start a new shell, affect it, and then have it terminate and have those effects evaporate.

Note that some changes, such as `git config --global`, are stored in *files*, rather than in your shell.  These changes *don't* evaporate when the shell vanishes.  That's a key difference: file system state is stored outside individual processes.  If everything `ssh-agent` did were stored in file system state, it *could* be made to work, but some of the things `ssh-agent` does are not stored there.

Comment: I added my alias to the bash configuration file `aliases.sh`, and everything worked correctly.
@torek, thanks for the explanation.